# Show is not a member of IFileOpenDialog

Tags: c, com

Good day.

I have been working with Microsoft Visual Studio  12 and trying to get a COM program working. However, I seem to be unable to access IFileOpenDialog's associated functions and components. I presume it must be something to do with my includes. Here are the error messages:

- Error 1   error C2039: 'Show' : is not a member of 'IFileOpenDialog'  c:\users\deylian\desktop\p\main.c   213 1   Project1
- Error 2   error C2039: 'GetResult' : is not a member of 'IFileOpenDialog' c:\users\deylian\desktop\p\main.c   217 1   Project1
- Error 3   error C2039: 'GetDisplayName' : is not a member of 'IShellItem' c:\users\deylian\desktop\p\main.c   220 1   Project1
- Error 4   error C2039: 'Release' : is not a member of 'IShellItem'    c:\users\deylian\desktop\p\main.c   226 1   Project1
- Error 5   error C2039: 'Release' : is not a member of 'IFileOpenDialog'   c:\users\deylian\desktop\p\main.c   229 1   Project1

  Here are the includes:

  #include < stdio.h >
  #include < stdlib.h >
  #include < string.h >
  #include < shobjidl.h >
  #include < SDL.h >
  #include < windows.h >

  And the code:

  ```
  HRESULT BasicFileOpen(){
  HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED |  COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
  if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
      IFileOpenDialog *pFileOpen = NULL;
      hr= CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_FileOpenDialog,
      NULL,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
      &IID_IFileOpenDialog,
      (void**)(&pFileOpen));

      if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
          hr=pFileOpen->Show(NULL);

          if (SUCCEEDED(hr)){
              IShellItem *pItem;
              hr = pFileOpen->GetResult(&pItem);
              if (SUCCEEDED(hr)){
                  PWSTR pszFilePath;
                  hr = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFilePath);

                  if (SUCCEEDED(hr)){
                      MessageBox(NULL, (LPCSTR)pszFilePath, (LPCSTR)"File Path", MB_OK);
                      CoTaskMemFree(pszFilePath);
                  }
                  pItem->Release();
              }
          }
          pFileOpen->Release();
      }
  }

  CoUninitialize();
  return hr;
  }
  ```

Thank you for your attention. Have a good day.

Comment: When using COM in C (as opposed to C++), you have to do something like `pFileOpen->pvtable->Show(pFileOpen, hwnd)` (I probably misspelled `pvtable` - I don't remember the exact name; look in the header).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Went digging a bit about it and found that it was lpVtbl so in the end it would be something like pFileOpen->lpVtbl->Show(pFileOpen, NULL).